# Hawtio as an OSGI bundle

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, hawtio

We have our own karaf based application and recently we decided to migrate our web console on hawtio as a plugin. Is there any possibility to append hawtio to our project as an OSGI bundle? i've downloaded hawtio project, but there is no maven module with packaging mode "bundle" or something like that. As an option of course we can get kar archive file, extract it and use its bundles. But that's not a native way at all. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clean solution for standalone unit testing, but apache karaf provides exam environment for such situations -  http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/writing-tests.html
So we can run tests with our application and hawtio in dev mode.
On production this leak of functionality is absent.

Answer (score 2):

Hello have you try to use the latest Hawtio for karaf `(hawtio-karaf)` available on maven repository?

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|io.hawt|hawtio-karaf|1.4.26|jar

It provide a `features.xml` that can be install on Karaf.

- First: install everything on your local maven repo.
- Second: launch your karaf.
- Third: run the command: `feature:repo-add mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/1.4.26/xml/features`
- Fourth: run the command: `feature:install hawtio`

According to the official website, the default URL is: `http://localhost:8181/hawtio/`

Let me know if it is working as you were expecting.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply. May be i did not explain it in a right way. We don't need to have hawtio as a karaf feature. We need an OSGI-ready bundle(jar) with all imports/exports sections. Moreover we might be able to inject hawtio into any OSGI container, not only felix/karaf, but in pax exam or equinox etc. It seems there is no fast and straight way to get these things done without additional actions and we would implement it ourself (and surely make a pull request :), right).

Comment: There is probably no simple way...you may investigate a bit the 'features.xml' to understand what are the mandatory jar and war and try to create a big fat jar/war using the 'maven-bundle-plugin'.

Comment: Yeap, seems so. But that's a dirty approach - to create your own copy of such java tool and always keep it in your project without possibility to update and extend it with some new third party plugins and features.